# C++ filling an array with numbers then returning a pointer to it

Tags: c++, pointers

Ive been faced with a problem recently that I can't think of a good way to solve.   I'm using a case structure to attempt to set attributes to a "character" that will be passed to an object constructor.

Example:

```
//note this is inside a function with a return type of int*
int selection;
cin >> selection;
int * iPtr;

switch(selection){

case 1:{
     int anArray[6] = {8,5,2,4,250,100} // str, dex, int, luck, hp, mp
     iPtr = anArray;
     return iPtr;
}

//more cases and such below
```

The issue that I'm having is that when I return my pointer it seems to be filled with a good amount of junk, rather than the information, rather than the information that I would be expecting it to hold.  Is that because the array gets destroyed at the end of the scope?  If so what should I do to make this work out how I'm hoping for it to (getting a pointer with the values that I want).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - anArray is declared on the stack. When the function exits, its stack frame is reclaimed, so it's no longer valid to refer to that memory. If you want the array to persist, allocate it on the heap instead:

```
int* anArray = new int[6]; // and initialize
return anArray;
```

Just remember to clean it up later at some point with the corresonding `delete[]`.

**EDIT**

You should prefer to use something that automatically manages resources for you, like in Praetorian's answer, so that you don't accidentally leak memory.

Comment: @HunderingThooves And don't forget, if you do this, the caller needs to `delete[]` the array after he's done using it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the array you've declared is indeed local to the function and no longer exists once the function exits. You can dynamically allocate an array using `new` and then have the caller `delete[]` the memory (but don't do this!), or modify your function to return an `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.

```
unique_ptr<int[]> anArray (new int[6]);
// do initialization
return anArray;
```

Now, the caller doesn't have to worry about freeing memory allocated by the function.

**EDIT:**

There are a couple of different ways to perform initialization of the `unique_ptr`.

```
anArray[0] = 8;
anArray[1] = 5;
// etc ...
```

OR

```
int init[6] = {8,5,2,4,250,100};
std::copy( &init[0], &init[0] + 6, &anArray[0] );
```

Comment: +1, this is the only acceptable use of manually allocated memory. I’m very tempted to downvote all other answers … they simply promote bad programming practices.

Comment: @Praetorian :  I take it by the initialization that unique_ptr is a template class, and that the () is an argument list for it? Given the code above, how would I initialize the pieces of a unique_ptr to be the values that I want?  It looks syntactically similar to a vector, but I've had no experience setting a unique_ptr;

Comment: @HunderingThooves I've updated the answer to show initialization. Nice spoonerism by the way :-)

Comment: Why thank you, ya know, I think you're the first person to actually know what a spoonerism is without me prattling on about it.  Well done.

Comment: @Pratorian I didn't realize that this solution used the boost library until I went to implement it and got smacked down by my compiler, this is going to be tricky.

Comment: @HunderingThooves It doesn't have to involve boost. unique_ptr is included in the <memory> header in C++0x under the std namespace. If you're using an older compiler look for it under the std::tr1 namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's because the local array is overwritten as the program runs. You can either declare the array static in the method (which would be a good idea for a fixed array like this), declare it at global scope, or allocate an array with `new` to return. The last alternative gives you the opportunity to have a different array returned for each call, but remember to deallocate the arrays after use.

Comment: Perfectly dead on.  You sir are a glorious man.

edit: Wait, assuming that I have an array that was created in a function, but needed until after I call the constructor, how could I delete the array?  I could delete the pointer to it since it would be used in main, but the array would be out of scope?

Comment: Not sure I follow the question, sorry. But if you return something from a function that eventually needs to be deleted, but you need to hang on to it for some undetermined period of time, you can always make your own copy of that thing, and delete the original.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the best answer is *not to return a pointer*. Instead, use a proper object instead of a C array or manually allocated memory and return this object:

```
std::vector<int> f() {
    std::vector<int> array;
    // fill array

    return array;
}
```

Using `new int[x]` (or whatever) is really, really deprecated in modern C++ code and is only deemed acceptable under very special circumstances. If you use it in normal code, this is a very obvious place for improvement. The same goes for other uses of manually managed memory. The whole strength of C++ lies in the fact that you *don’t* have to manage your own memory, thus avoiding a multitude of hard to track bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because the array you created is created on the stack, and when you return, the part of the stack that you were at is overwritten (presumably by a debug process).

To avoid this, you would write

```
int* anArray = new int[6];
// fill the array
return anArray;
```

In this case, you will also have to delete the returned result when you are finished with it, such as in

```
int* dataArray = getTheArray();
// Use the dataArray
delete [] dataArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate array on the heap

```
int* anArray = new int[6];
```

You will have to delete it manually:

```
delete[] iPtr;
```

Comment: No, you're using the wrong form of `delete`. When you allocate an array you must `delete[]`.